# Pass boxed trait as a reference

Tags: rust

So I have a trait that I want to pass around and do some dynamic method dispatching on. I have one method that needs the trait as a boxed pointer, but it needs to call another method that uses a reference to the trait. So something like:

```
trait Foo {
    fn do_something(&self);
}

struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn do_something(&self) {}
}

fn foo_as_box(foo : Box<Foo>) {
    foo_as_ref(&foo);
}

fn foo_as_ref(foo : &Foo) {
    foo.do_something();
}

fn main() {
    let boxed_foo = box Bar as Box<Foo>;
    foo_as_box(boxed_foo);
}
```

But, I get an error on this code

```
error: failed to find an implementation of trait Foo for Box Foo<no-bounds>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler will convert `Box<Foo>` into `&Foo` as needed automatically. You can just say

```
foo_as_ref(foo);
```

and it will work.

This doesn't necessarily work in more complex situations. Which is to say, the compiler can't always tell that you want that conversion.

Now that [DST](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12938) has been implemented, you can say `&*foo` to do the conversion.

In the past the only way to force it was a `let`-binding, as in

```
let ref_foo: &Foo = foo;
```

Of course, your use-case is simple enough that you don't need this.

Comment: Should the let-binding work for something like Arc<Box Foo> to &Foo as well?

Comment: @AJD: Sure, if you deref the `Arc` (not that it actually has to be `Arc<Box<Foo:Send+Share>>` because `Arc` requires `Send+Share`). `let boxed_foo = box Bar as Box<Foo:Send+Share>; let arc_foo = Arc::new(boxed_foo); let ref_foo: &Foo = *arc_foo;`

Comment: Is there a runtime cost of `&*` used here?

Comment: @SomeName `&*` will invoke `Deref::deref()` but in most cases this should be trivial and probably get optimized out.